# Pedir datos por teclado JavaScript en la misma pagina

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas estoy comenzando con Javascript y queria saber como pedir datos por teclado sin utilizar la funcion "prompt" ya que te abre una venta emergente por asi decirlo, quiero programarlo dentro de la pagina web y que sea todo dentro del "body", espero que comprendan la situación.
Realice un pequeño ejercicio para tener una idea pero no quiero utilizar el "prompt"

```
<html>

<h1>APLICACION</h1>

<p>BIENVENIDOS A LA APLICACION</p>


<script>

var x,y;
 x = prompt("Ingrese numero uno: ");
 y = prompt("Ingrese numero dos: ");

if (x==y) {
    document.write("Mensaje que aparece si son iguales");
}

</script>


</html>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo elaboras con inputs? Que el usuario escriba y mediante javascript y CSS se oculte los input y muestre el mensaje (por ejemplo).

Comment: ¿en qué exactamente necesitas ayuda?

Comment: Necesito ayuda que en el texto donde dice "Ingrese numero" aparezca en el sitio web y que al lado pueda ingresar el numero, hay una forma de hacerlo
?

Comment: Seguro que si, pero ¿qué has intentado en ese sentido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrias necesitar una introduccion con mas detalle al uso de los formularios web, te aconsejo que revises algún tutorial como https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp.

Puedes intentar lo mas basico usando elementos `input` para ingresar texto:

```html
    <h1>APLICACION</h1>
    <p>BIENVENIDOS A LA APLICACION</p>
    <form>
      Ingrese numero uno: <input type="text" name="numero1">
      <br>
      Ingrese numero dos: <input type="text" name="numero2" >
      <br>
    </form>
```

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que andaba buscando pero ahora tendre que investigar como tomar esos numeros que ingrese como "variables" para hacer mi comparacion con el if (numero1==numero2), me sirvio gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Veo que te han mencionado acerca de usar elementos input para permitir al usuario ingresar los datos, así que te aporto un poco sobre como tomar los datos ingresados por el usuario para trabajar con ellos.

Para manipular el elemento input creado, debes seleccionarlo en javascript. Una manera sencilla de hacerlo es agregando al elemento HTML un id.

En tu archivo HTML tendrias que hacer lo siguiente con input.

```
<input type="text" name="numero1" id="valor1">
```

Luego, en tu archivo javascript seleccionas el elemento a partir de su id usando el metodo getElementById():

```
let valor1 = document.getElementById('valor1');
```

ya con esto tienes acceso input y podras usar el valor de los datos ingresados por el usuario usando la propiedad value:

```
console.log(valor1.value);
```